# How can I take the data from a screen to another in flutter and create something with these data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have in my main screen a list of locations and a floating button when it's pressed it opens a form and the user enters a parameters to create a new location on the main screen
but when I press on the submit button on the form it takes me to the main screen and the location is not added
I hope someone can help

***this is the main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:my_locations/models/Location.dart';
import 'package:my_locations/data/locations.dart';
import 'package:my_locations/models/MainScreen.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root
// of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    title: "My Locations",
    theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new MainScreen());
 }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
```

***this is the main screen***

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
 import 'package:my_locations/models/Location.dart';
 import 'package:my_locations/data/locations.dart';
 import 'package:my_locations/models/Details.dart';
 import 'package:my_locations/models/MyForm.dart';

 class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Location> locations = [
  Location(
    id: 1,
    name: "The Egyptian Museum",
    description:
        "The Museum of Egyptian Antiquities, known commonly as the Egyptian Museum or Museum 
            of Cairo, in Cairo",
    theme: "egyptian heritage",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.mazadatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Egyptian-Museum-in- 
                 Cairo2.jpg",
    locationUrl:"https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+of+Giza/@29.9792391,31.1320132,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424!8m2!3d29.9792345!4d31.1342019")                                                                                                ,
  Location(
    id: 2,
    name: "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    description:
        "The Great Pyramid of Giza ",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Kheops-Pyramid.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+of+Giza/@29.9792391,31.1320132,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424!8m2!3d29.9792345!4d31.1342019"),
Location(
    id: 3,
    name: "Abu Simbel temples",
    description:
        "The Abu Simbel temples are two massive rock-cut temples at Abu Simbel",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.worldatlas.com/upload/4f/c6/2f/shutterstock-397432201.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Abu+Simbel+Temples/@22.3372368,31.6236103,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143aa988b126055b:0xa7d3cc6618f898d2!8m2!3d22.3372319!4d31.625799"),
Location(
    id: 4,
    name: "Philae",
    description:
        "Philae is an island in the reservoir of the Aswan Low Dam, downstream of the Aswan Dam",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6RX--BMe-PA/UHAa8fRiKaI/AAAAAAAABXA/5v9KcZ3HCvY/s1600/IMGP2321.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Philae/@24.0134126,32.8678317,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143662bfbe299cbf:0xd571ef8bf3780147!8m2!3d24.01266!4d32.8775404"),
Location(
    id: 5,
    name: "Luxor Temple",
    description:
        "The Luxor Temple",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://lp-cms-production.imgix.net/2019-06/19e21d328924e00b3d35b92fc9f380ac-luxor-temple.jpg?auto=compress&crop=center&fit=crop&format=auto&h=416&w=960",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Luxor+Temple/@25.6995068,32.6368622,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x144915c41edadf61:0x7693895c346c7d81!8m2!3d25.699502!4d32.6390509")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My Locations")),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: locations.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Card(
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(locations[index].imageUrl),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              Details(locations[index].id),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    title: Text(locations[index].name),
                    subtitle: Text(locations[index].theme),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyForm()));
      },
    ));
  }
 }
```

***this is the details page***

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
   import 'package:my_locations/models/Location.dart';
   import 'package:my_locations/data/locations.dart';
   import 'package:my_locations/models/MainScreen.dart';

   class Details extends StatelessWidget {
     int i = 0;
     Details(int i) {
       this.i = i - 1;
     }

 List<Location> locations = [
Location(
    id: 1,
    name: "The Egyptian Museum",
    description:
        "The Museum of Egyptian Antiquities",
    theme: "egyptian heritage",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.mazadatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Egyptian-Museum-in-Cairo2.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        'https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Egyptian+Museum/@30.0209745,31.1411905,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1segyptian+museum!3m4!1s0x0:0x520da52b3a7a660f!8m2!3d30.0475784!4d31.2336159'),
Location(
    id: 2,
    name: "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    description:
        "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Kheops-Pyramid.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+of+Giza/@29.9792391,31.1320132,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424!8m2!3d29.9792345!4d31.1342019"),
Location(
    id: 3,
    name: "Abu Simbel temples",
    description:
        "The Abu Simbel temples are two massive rock-cut temples at Abu Simbel ",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.worldatlas.com/upload/4f/c6/2f/shutterstock-397432201.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Abu+Simbel+Temples/@22.3372368,31.6236103,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143aa988b126055b:0xa7d3cc6618f898d2!8m2!3d22.3372319!4d31.625799"),
Location(
    id: 4,
    name: "Philae",
    description:
        "Philae is an island in the reservoir of the Aswan Low Dam, downstream of the Aswan Dam and Lake Nasser",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6RX--BMe-PA/UHAa8fRiKaI/AAAAAAAABXA/5v9KcZ3HCvY/s1600/IMGP2321.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Philae/@24.0134126,32.8678317,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143662bfbe299cbf:0xd571ef8bf3780147!8m2!3d24.01266!4d32.8775404"),
Location(
    id: 5,
    name: "Luxor Temple",
    description:
        "The Luxor Temple",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://lp-cms-production.imgix.net/2019-06/19e21d328924e00b3d35b92fc9f380ac-luxor-temple.jpg?auto=compress&crop=center&fit=crop&format=auto&h=416&w=960",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Luxor+Temple/@25.6995068,32.6368622,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x144915c41edadf61:0x7693895c346c7d81!8m2!3d25.699502!4d32.6390509"),
        ];

    void _launchURL() async => await canLaunch(locations[i].locationUrl)
       ? await launch(locations[i].locationUrl)
       : throw 'Could not launch $locations[i].locationUrl';

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Details"),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _launchURL,
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
        child: Text(locations[i].name),
      ),
      Image.network(locations[i].imageUrl),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
        child: Text(locations[i].description),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
   }
 }
```

***this is the form class***

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
  import 'package:my_locations/models/Location.dart';
  import 'package:my_locations/data/locations.dart';
  import 'package:my_locations/models/MainScreen.dart';

  class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   MyCustomFormState createState() {
     return MyCustomFormState();
    }

    List<Location> locations = [
Location(
    id: 1,
    name: "The Egyptian Museum",
    description:
        "The Museum of Egyptian Antiquities",
    theme: "egyptian heritage",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.mazadatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Egyptian-Museum-in-Cairo2.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        'https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Egyptian+Museum/@30.0209745,31.1411905,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1segyptian+museum!3m4!1s0x0:0x520da52b3a7a660f!8m2!3d30.0475784!4d31.2336159'),
Location(
    id: 2,
    name: "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    description:
        "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Kheops-Pyramid.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+of+Giza/@29.9792391,31.1320132,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424!8m2!3d29.9792345!4d31.1342019"),
Location(
    id: 3,
    name: "Abu Simbel temples",
    description:
        "The Abu Simbel temples are two massive rock-cut temples at Abu Simbel",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.worldatlas.com/upload/4f/c6/2f/shutterstock-397432201.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Abu+Simbel+Temples/@22.3372368,31.6236103,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143aa988b126055b:0xa7d3cc6618f898d2!8m2!3d22.3372319!4d31.625799"),
Location(
    id: 4,
    name: "Philae",
    description:
        "Philae is an island in the reservoir of the Aswan Low Dam, downstream of the Aswan Dam and Lake Nasser",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6RX--BMe-PA/UHAa8fRiKaI/AAAAAAAABXA/5v9KcZ3HCvY/s1600/IMGP2321.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Philae/@24.0134126,32.8678317,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143662bfbe299cbf:0xd571ef8bf3780147!8m2!3d24.01266!4d32.8775404"),
Location(
    id: 5,
    name: "Luxor Temple",
    description:
        "The Luxor Temple",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "http://justfunfacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/luxor-temple-colonnade.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Luxor+Temple/@25.6995068,32.6368622,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x144915c41edadf61:0x7693895c346c7d81!8m2!3d25.699502!4d32.6390509"),
      ];
    }

  class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyForm> {
   List<Location> locations = [
Location(
    id: 1,
    name: "The Egyptian Museum",
    description:
        "The Museum of Egyptian Antiquities",
    theme: "egyptian heritage",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.mazadatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Egyptian-Museum-in-Cairo2.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        'https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Egyptian+Museum/@30.0209745,31.1411905,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1segyptian+museum!3m4!1s0x0:0x520da52b3a7a660f!8m2!3d30.0475784!4d31.2336159'),
Location(
    id: 2,
    name: "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    description:
        "The Great Pyramid of Giza",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Kheops-Pyramid.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Great+Pyramid+of+Giza/@29.9792391,31.1320132,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14584587ac8f291b:0x810c2f3fa2a52424!8m2!3d29.9792345!4d31.1342019"),
Location(
    id: 3,
    name: "Abu Simbel temples",
    description:
        "The Abu Simbel temples are two massive rock-cut temples at Abu Simbel",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://www.worldatlas.com/upload/4f/c6/2f/shutterstock-397432201.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Abu+Simbel+Temples/@22.3372368,31.6236103,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143aa988b126055b:0xa7d3cc6618f898d2!8m2!3d22.3372319!4d31.625799"),
Location(
    id: 4,
    name: "Philae",
    description:
        "Philae is an island in the reservoir of the Aswan Low Dam, downstream of the Aswan Dam and Lake Nasser",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6RX--BMe-PA/UHAa8fRiKaI/AAAAAAAABXA/5v9KcZ3HCvY/s1600/IMGP2321.jpg",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Philae/@24.0134126,32.8678317,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x143662bfbe299cbf:0xd571ef8bf3780147!8m2!3d24.01266!4d32.8775404"),
Location(
    id: 5,
    name: "Luxor Temple",
    description:
        "The Luxor Temple",
    theme: "pharaonic",
    imageUrl:
        "https://lp-cms-production.imgix.net/2019-06/19e21d328924e00b3d35b92fc9f380ac-luxor-temple.jpg?auto=compress&crop=center&fit=crop&format=auto&h=416&w=960",
    locationUrl:
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Luxor+Temple/@25.6995068,32.6368622,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x144915c41edadf61:0x7693895c346c7d81!8m2!3d25.699502!4d32.6390509")
    ];

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  String name;
  String theme;
  String description;
  String imageUrl;
  String locationUrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Form"),
  ),
  body: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Location name'),
            //controller: name,

            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return value = name;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Theme'),
            //controller: theme,

            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return value = theme;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Full description'),
            //controller: description,

            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return value = description;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Image URL'),
            //controller: imageUrl,

            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return value = imageUrl;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Location URL'),
            //controller: locationUrl,

            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return value = locationUrl;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {

              var newloc = new Location(
                id: 6,
                name: name,
                description: description,
                theme: theme,
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                locationUrl: locationUrl,
              );
              
              locations.add(newloc);
              
              Navigator.pop(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));

              //MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));

              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
                // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
              }
            },
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So , you can await for your form when you open it to give you back a result like this

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyForm()));
```

and when you are done with your form done push again the main screen just get back like this

```
Navigator.pop(context, newloc);
```

after that in your mainScreen add your new location to your location list , but you are probably gonna need a stateful widget . like this

```
setState(() {
 locations.add(result);
});
```